# Draw Lines Between Points Contained in a Vector (VC++)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, gdi, pen

I want to draw line segments between points contained in a vector and display them in a window.

Currently, this is what I have:

```
case WM_PAINT:
    hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
  //Draw lines to screen.
    using std::vector;
    using std::iterator;
    extern vector<int> euler_time;
    extern vector<int> euler_soln;
    hPen = CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 1, RGB(255, 25, 5));
    SelectObject(hdc, hPen);
    for(std::vector<int>::size_type i = 0; i != euler_time.size(); i++){
    MoveToEx(hdc,euler_time[i],euler_soln[i],NULL);
    LineTo(hdc,euler_time[i],euler_soln[i]);
    }
    EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
```

This is contained in a larger .CPP source file generated as when creating a standard Win32 Application.

As you can see, my idea was to iterate through my vector using a `for` loop and then use `LineTo` and `MoveToEx` to go to the next point and draw a line form the previous one.

Currently I get a completely blank window with no errors. Suggestions?

EDIT:

So I'm guessing the break point message mentioned in the comments below was caused by my loading the external vector. The vector is an output of a `for` loop in another .CPP file.

```
    using std::vector;
    using std::iterator;
    extern vector<int> euler_time;
    extern vector<int> euler_soln;
```

And the loop in the other .CPP file:

```
for (double t = a; t < b; t += h )
{
    std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(3) << t << " " << y << "\n";
    euler_time.insert (euler_time.begin(),t); // Insert the values of t and y into the respective vectors.
    euler_soln.insert (euler_soln.begin(),y);
    y += h * f(t, y);
}
```

EDIT 2:

So I started with the Polyline API. I created an array of type `const POINT*` called `Pt` and attempted to assign the values `t` and `y_n` to it. I then called `Polyline` and told it to draw from the array.

I end up with no errors and a blank window again.

From the Window CPP file:

```
    extern const POINT* Pt;
  //Draw lines to screen.
    hPen = CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 1, RGB(255, 25, 5));
    SelectObject(hdc, hPen);
    Polyline(hdc,Pt,10);
```

From the other CPP file:

```
const POINT * Pt;
void euler(F f, int y0, int a, int b, int h ) // defines a class of type     "void" (returns nothing); gives it parameters: function F, doubles: y0, a, b, h
{
int y_n = y0;
int t = a;
for (int t = a; t < b; t += h ) // creates a for loop beginning with time t = a and ending with t ~= b with stepsize h.
{
    std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(3) << t << " " << y_n << "\n"; // Calls the standard output from std, with floating-point numbers with precision 3; assigns the variable t, then a space, then variable y, then a new line.
    LONG x = t;
    LONG y = y_n;
    y_n += h * f(t, y_n); // y increases by h * f(t,y) where f is the derivative y' until the condition is met y ~= b.
}
std::cout << "done\n"; // Print "done"
}
```

EDIT 3:

I'm now trying to use `vector<POINT>` to create a vector with the point values. However, my attempt results in the following error:

```
6   IntelliSense: no instance of overloaded function "std::vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::insert [with _Ty=POINT, _Alloc=std::allocator<POINT>]" matches the argument list
        argument types are: (std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<POINT>>>, double)
        object type is: std::vector<POINT, std::allocator<POINT>>   c:\Users\ahlroth\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Euler\Euler\eulerclass.cpp   22
```

My code is below:

```
using std::vector;
vector<POINT> Pt;
POINT euler(F f, double y0, double a, double b, double h, vector<POINT> Pt) // defines a class of type "void" (returns nothing); gives it parameters: function F, doubles: y0, a, b, h
{
    double y_n = y0;
    double t = a;
    for (double t = a; t < b; t += h ) // creates a for loop beginning with time t = a and ending with t ~= b with stepsize h.
{
    std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(3) << t << " " << y_n << "\n"; // Calls the standard output from std, with floating-point numbers with precision 3; assigns the variable t, then a space, then variable y, then a new line.
    Pt.insert(Pt.begin(),t);
    y_n += h * f(t, y_n); // y increases by h * f(t,y) where f is the derivative y' until the condition is met y ~= b.
}
return Pt;
std::cout << "done\n"; // Print "done"
```

}

The error is for this line:
`Pt.insert(Pt.begin(),t);`

EDIT: See this post for an [answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28600950/plotting-euler-integration-using-polyline-c)

Comment: What are the values of `t`? `a`?  `b`?  `h`?  Second, you should be using integers, not floating point values for loop counters.  If any of those values in the the `for` are `< 1.0` or is not an exact integer, that loop has a good chance of iterating a differing number of times, depending on optimizations and compiler settings.

Comment: `void euler(F f, double y0, double a, double b, double h ) `

It's an euler integration class.

Comment: Well, be aware that your program may run differently in `release` mode as opposed to `debug`.  Floating point calculations are not exact, so be prepared for extra or missing iterations within the loop when you compare debug and release versions of your application.  If you do see an issue, make sure you search SO for explanations for the differences w.r.t. floating point.

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are drawing line segments of length zero.

Only do a MoveTo on the first point, then do LineTo on the rest.

Comment: Thanks, but still no cigar. I end up with the same result. I tried changing to:
`MoveToEx(hdc,euler_time[0],euler_soln[0],NULL);`
`LineTo(hdc,euler_time[i],euler_soln[i]);`

Comment: And did you get rid of the move calls within the loop also?

Comment: Ah, so I just moved the MoveToEx() to outside the loop. Now I get:

`'DrawTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\oleaut32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Second Chance Assertion Failed: File c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\vector, Line 1140
DrawTest.exe has triggered a breakpoint.
Second Chance Assertion Failed: File c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\vector, Line 1141
DrawTest.exe has triggered a breakpoint.
Microsoft Visual Studio C Runtime Library has detected a fatal error in DrawTest.exe.`

Comment: @RobbieCapps So what is being asserted?  The Visual Studio debugger should have taken you to the line that failed the assertion.

Comment: I'm sorry... I'm a complete novice. When I click `break`, it takes me to a line in `dbghook.c`: 

`void __cdecl _CRT_DEBUGGER_HOOK(int _Reserved)
{
    /* assign 0 to _debugger_hook_dummy so that the function is not folded in retail */
    (_Reserved);
    _debugger_hook_dummy = 0;
}`

Comment: @RobbieCapps Go to the call stack and see what function *you* wrote that led to this code.  It isn't the code you posted that is an error.

Comment: It's the vector subscript (out of range) for the MoveToEx call.

Comment: Ah. You need a `<` check instead of the `!=` check - the index is zero-based, so the last index is one less the length.

Comment: Once you get the bugs sorted out consider using the Polyline API instead of the moveto/lineto loop. Faster and easier.

Comment: Ok, now I get a new break: unsigned integer position.

Comment: @ScottMcP-MVP I'm now trying to use the Polyline API; how can I assign values in a POINT array for the Polyline?

Comment: You could use a vector<POINT> and replace your euler_time and euler_soln vectors with the x and y members of each POINT.

Comment: @ScottMcP-MVP Could you please check EDIT 3 in my answer above? I think I'm close, but I must be missing something crucial when dealing with a vector<POINT>.

Comment: The second parameter to insert needs to be a POINT. Put  a POINT variable in your loop. Set its .x and .y members. Then insert the POINT. Loop again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70423/discussion-between-robbie-capps-and-scottmcp-mvp).